# Java - how to return to a parent method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a method which should check in a guest to a room if the password matches. The method should also return that room.

```
public Room checkIn(String password, String guestName) {
        assert (guestName != null);
        if (this.password.testWord(password) && roomList.stream().allMatch(r -> r.getGuest().getName() != guestName)) {
            roomList.forEach(r -> {
                if (r.getGuest() == null) {
                    new Guest(guestName).checkin(r);
                    return r;
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Eclipse gives me an error about returning within the `forEach()` method, since `forEach()` shouldn't return anything. I'm trying to have the `checkIn()` method return the room. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Use `for (Room r : roomList)` to iterate instead.

Comment: `Room r = roomList.stream().filter(r -> r.getGuest() == null).findFirst();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Wouldn't `findFirst` return an `Optional`?

Comment: @Henrik yep! And I don't even have the excuse of being on my phone ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use `Stream.findFirst()` to get the first matching element:

```
Optional<Room> r = roomList.stream().filter(r -> r.getGuest() == null).findFirst();
if (r.isPresent()) {
  new Guest(guestName).checkin(r.get());
  return r.get();
}
```

Comment: The if struct could be changed to `r.map(room -> new Guest(guestName).checkin(room)).orElse(null)`. Not sure it's more readable, though.